# Performing a git command in a powershell script

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am working on a few powershell scripts to automate some common tasks i do every day.

I would like to be able to write one that does a pull of the latest code using git and opens the VS solution. I can do the opening of the solution, what i need help with is calling `git pull` from a powershell script.

I tried `git pull <repo name>` in my script, however it doesn't recognise the git command.

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need `git` in your `PATH` environment variable, or have an *App Paths* entry for `git` or specify the full path to your `git` executable.

Comment: Thanks, once i read your answer i couldn't believe i hadn't checked the git was in my PATH variable. I assumed it would have been set when git was installed.